# Can Welding Jar target itself?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

We had this issue come up in a game last night, and we weren't sure how to handle it. Player A had [Welding Jar](http://magiccards.info/mi/en/274.html) and another artifact in play. Player B cast [Naturalize](http://magiccards.info/m14/en/186.html) targeting the Welding Jar. In response, Player A sacrificed Welding Jar to regenerate itself.

Is this possible to do? I understand that Welding Jar is going into the graveyard either way, as sacrificed creatures can't be regenerated, but can Welding Jar legally target itself with it's own ability?

EDIT: If this seems non-sensical, let's assume that Player A has something in play like [Furnace Celebration](http://magiccards.info/som/en/90.html) that gives them a benefit for sacrificing the Welding Jar.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Welding Jar can target itself.

When you cast a spell or activate an ability, you choose targets (601.2c) before paying costs (601.2g). So the Welding Jar is still on the battlefield when it's time to choose targets, and is a valid target for its own ability.

That ability will fizzle, of course, since you've already put Welding Jar in the graveyard by the time it would resolve.